# Split train and test set df contains location points of multiple users

Tags: python, split, neural-network, training-data

df == location points of multiple users data

```
    tslot             user location point
0   2015-12-04 13:00:00 0   4356
1   2015-12-04 13:15:00 0   4356
2   2015-12-04 13:30:00 0   4356
3   2015-12-04 13:45:00 0   4356
4   2015-12-04 14:00:00 0   4356
5   2015-12-04 14:15:00 0   4356
6   2015-12-04 14:30:00 0   4356
7   2015-12-04 14:45:00 0   4356
8   2015-12-04 15:00:00 0   7645
... ... ... ...
616688  2015-12-10 18:30:00 38204   820
616689  2015-12-10 18:45:00 38204   1081
616690  2015-12-10 19:00:00 38204   672
616691  2015-12-10 19:15:00 38204   694
616692  2015-12-10 19:30:00 38204   46
616693  2015-12-10 19:45:00 38204   360
616694  2015-12-10 20:00:00 38204   1380
616695  2015-12-10 20:15:00 38204   1380
616696  2015-12-10 20:30:00 38204   1380
616697  2015-12-10 20:45:00 38204   1381
616698  2015-12-10 21:00:00 38204   1380
```

Each user data is separated by using the below code:

```
users = ["0", "6356"]
df_ = {}
for i in users:
    df_[i] = newdataframe[newdataframe.user== int(i)]
```

i tried to split the train adn test data set by using

```
def split(dataframe, border, col):
    return dataframe.loc[:border,col], dataframe.loc[border:,col]

df_new = {}
for i in users:
    df_new[i] = {}
    df_new[i]["Train"], df_new[i]["Test"] = split(df_[i], "500", "location point")
```

My requirement is to get the training set of size 500 rows and the remaining for test data set. How to split the training and testing values for each user.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure your code works as expected

```
import pandas as pd

df_rawdata = pd.DataFrame({'user':[1,2,1,2,1],'location point':[4,11,10,9,7]})

users = ["1", "2"]
df_ = {}
for i in users:
    df_[i] = df_rawdata[df_rawdata.user== int(i)]

def split(dataframe, border, col):
    return dataframe.loc[:border,col], dataframe.loc[border:,col]

df_new = {}
for i in users:
    df_new[i] = {}
    df_new[i]["Train"], df_new[i]["Test"] = split(df_[i], "2", "location point")
```

then

```
print(df_new["1"]['Train'])
```

gives

```
0     4
2    10
Name: location point, dtype: int64
```

i.e. the indices and location points for the first 2 datapoints of user 1

and

```
print(df_new["1"]['Test'])
```

gives the last